# How autosize items to show by 2 items in collection view with horizontal orientation Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, collectionview

I have this xaml structure to display categories in CollectionView.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalItemSpacing="2"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type m:Category}">
                        <Grid Padding="5">
                            <Frame CornerRadius="10" IsClippedToBounds="True" BorderColor="LightGray">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

I get this result.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoHlu.png. But I want to show by 2 categories like on this picture   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3nZK.png. How can I autosize them by width, so there was not parts of other categories?

Comment: have you tried a CarouselView?

Comment: It works better, but I still can't get result like on 2nd image. I want category to take a half of carouselview width https://prnt.sc/24ofxfu

Comment: you will probably need to calculate the size in code